# regexp freebie ... how do I do this?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What is the correct way to do this?

```
<?php
$word = 'dogcatdog';
preg_match( '/do'."[^0-9]".'atdog/i', $word, $matches );
print_r($matches);
?>
```

I want to return "gc".

I keep getting an error: "Unknown modifier '['".

Comment: Could you fix your code? Currently it would give a syntax error.

Comment: Please post the original code, you are missing a quote or 2.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister - Too many quotes as it happens

Comment: @nickc - lol, the OP already states they're getting an error, if they could fix the code themselves, they wouldn't be here asking.

Comment: @user522962 - What reason did you have for using `[^0-9]` in the original code? To me, it's interesting the way people learn about regex, since it can seem very cryptic at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well if two dogs are surrounding a cat the first thing we can observe is that the cat will start to hiss a lot, this produces a "Hsssss". Then the dogs will start to bark and growl a lot, this gives us a "Grrr Grrr BARK". So together this will produce something like "Hsssss Grrr Grrr Hsssss BARK BARK Hsssss Grrr". So now, remember we want "gc" as our final result we apply the following

```
$word = 'dogcatdog';
preg_match("[r]+", $word, $matches);
preg_match("(BARK)", $word, $matches);
preg_match("[Hs]+", $word, $matches);
$matches = "c";
preg_match("[G]+", $word, $matchesFinal);
$matches =  $matchesFinal[0] . $matches;
```

and presto!

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match( '/do([a-z]{2})atdog/i', $word, $matches );
```

Should get it, you would never do `[^0-9]` if your are trying to find `gc`. That's just going to find any non-digit character, so would include all punctuation, well anything except 0..9.

Of course, if you really **just** want to match `gc` within the string, you'd do.

```
preg_match( '/do(gc)atdog/i', $word, $matches );
```

However, that seems fairly pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specific PHP syntax, but try this:

```
preg_match( '/do([^0-9]+)atdog/i', $word, $matches );
```

Answer (score 0):

(The string syntax in your example was wrong.)

If you want to capture something, you need to enclose it in `(` paranthesis `)`.

```
preg_match( '/do([^0-9]+)atdog/i', $word, $matches );
```

In this case `gc` would appear in `$matches[1]`. The result array is always enumerated by the capture braces.

And here is a nice list of tools that can help with constructing regular expressions, useful to get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Comment: `[^0-9]` doesn't match `gc`, but only one character, so, in this case, the match fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i corrected your syntax errors:

```
<?php
$word = 'dogcatdog';
preg_match("/do([^0-9]+)atdog/i", $word, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```